# Django form scenarios?

Tags: django, django-models

I have a user account page where they can edit their username, password and email address.

For obvious reasons I want to split this page into two forms, one to edit username and email, the other to edit the password.

Now, all is dandy when I think of how to create two forms, `UserEditAccountForm` and `UserEditPasswordForm` but is there a way, like in frameworks I am used to, to have one form with two different scenarios?

So that essentially I can use one `FormModel` but with different scenarios for the `POST`?

Comment: The only way is to have an if/else statement which I'm not a huge fan of

Comment: @Sayse nor am I frankly, it is like pure butchery

Comment: Not sure if this qualifies as an answer but django likes to keep everything with one purpose and imo that helps a lot to keep things clean, depending on what your "different scenarios" are, having a generic `FormView` might give you options but that would still require two urls

Comment: @Sayse I think that does, ideology, if applicable to explain why something cannot be done is always a good answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the first things it says on the [django homepage](https://www.djangoproject.com/) is that django "encourages rapid development and clean, pragmatic design"... and they are really strict about this (which is why its great!). The framework is set up in a way that forces you to consider giving every view one specific purpose, which means that using a views post for two different purposes isn't possible without a fugly if statement.

Your options:

- Consider if you really need to have two purposes for one view, its perfectly acceptible for different views to use the same template
- Look into making your view generic, django's default generic views are pretty powerful on their own and depending on your scenarios it may be a viable option
- Butchery

[image]